# Resizing the label font in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am wondering if there is a possible way to resize the label of the node to a bigger font. For example I have something like this [image: Glucose node]

And I want to resize the "Glc" label. I tried something like:

```
CREATE (Glc:Initial_substrate {name: "Glc"}, font = 20 px)
```

or

```
CREATE (Glc:Initial_substrate {name: "Glc", font = 20px})
```

But nothing seems to work. When I am googling I just find out how to resize the node circles not the label itself. Anyone here can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking about modifying the font size used by the neo4j Browser. The Browser's styling is not controlled by putting properties in your nodes (and would be a bad idea).

Instead, you should use the `:help style` command in the Bowser to see how to use the `:style` command to get, edit, and update the style settings for all nodes/relationships as well as specific node labels and relationship types.

For convenience, here is an excerpt from the help display:

> **Style**
>
> The `:style` command lets you modify the visual aspects of your graph.
>
> **Usage:** `:style <action>`
>
> **Actions:**
>
> `:style` - Display the currently active style. Select and copy to edit it locally.
>
> `:style <url>` - load style
>   from an URL. Note that the server hosting the style file must accept
>   cross origin requests.
>
> `:style reset` - Reset styling to it's default.